# Getting error while adding a new node to existing single node in vertica

Tags: vertica

I am adding a new node to existing single node in vertica, I'm getting this error

Error: scp failed. Tried to retrieve '/opt/vertica/log/verify-latest.xml' from '103.++.++.++'
System prerequisites failed.  Threshold = WARN
    Hint: Fix above failures or use --failure-threshold

Installation FAILED with errors.

What I have to do ? Need help :(

Comment: `scp failed` suggests some problems with ssh connectivity, has passwordless ssh been set up between the two nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah I got the answer

Edit `/opt/vertica/share/eggs/vertica/network/scp.py` file with add where scp -P < Port >, you have to menstion your port there.